# How to implement PDF Viewer to SwiftUI application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm building an app, which displays PDFs, but I don't know how to display a PDF file using SwiftUI. I found tutorials on how to display a PDF file using UIKit, but there are no tutorials about SwiftUI. Can anyone help me?

I'm also trying to do that using MVVM design pattern. If there's someone, who can help me, I will be extremely grateful!

[image: File structure]

[image: App]

### Code:

#### HomeView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    
    var deeds: [Deed] = deedsData
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                List(deeds) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "doc.fill")
                            Text(item.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("title")
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView(deeds: deedsData)
    }
}
```

#### DeedModel.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Deed: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var URL: String
}

let deedsData: [Deed] = [
    Deed(title: NSLocalizedString("civilCode", comment: "Civil code"), URL: "https://isap.sejm.gov.pl/isap.nsf/download.xsp/WDU19640160093/U/D19640093Lj.pdf"),
    Deed(title: NSLocalizedString("penalCode", comment: "Penal code"), URL: "https://isap.sejm.gov.pl/isap.nsf/download.xsp/WDU19970880553/U/D19970553Lj.pdf"),
    Deed(title: NSLocalizedString("civilProcedureCode", comment: "Code of civil procedure"), URL: "https://isap.sejm.gov.pl/isap.nsf/download.xsp/WDU19640430296/U/D19640296Lj.pdf"),
    Deed(title: NSLocalizedString("familyAndGuardianshipCode", comment: "Family and guardianship code"), URL: "http://isap.sejm.gov.pl/isap.nsf/download.xsp/WDU19640090059/U/D19640059Lj.pdf"),
    Deed(title: NSLocalizedString("laborCode", comment: "Labor code"), URL: "https://isap.sejm.gov.pl/isap.nsf/download.xsp/WDU19740240141/U/D19740141Lj.pdf"),
]
```

Anyone knows how can I do that in MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To display a PDF with Apple-only frameworks, you'll need to use UIKit, via a `UIViewRepresentable`:

```
import PDFKit
import SwiftUI

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView

    let data: Data
    let singlePage: Bool

    init(_ data: Data, singlePage: Bool = false) {
        self.data = data
        self.singlePage = singlePage
    }

    func makeUIView(context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> UIViewType {
        // Create a `PDFView` and set its `PDFDocument`.
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        if singlePage {
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        }
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: UIViewType, context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
    }
}
```

then `PDFKitRepresentedView` can be used in your view hierarchy.

This takes a `Data` object as input, so you'll need to convert those `URL` objects you have to `Data` via a network call first.  So, you might do something like:

```
@State var data : Data? 

...

.onAppear {
  self.data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
}
```

Keep in mind this is vastly simplified -- you'll want to do some error handling, etc.  Might want to do some searching on SwiftUI network calls.

Comment: using this solution does load the PDF, but, the logs now show this: `=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1474688 ===`. To make that go away I have to comment out the `pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)` in  `updateUIView(....`. Why is that?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing what you're doing to trigger `updateUIView`. Actually, given how cryptic those attribute graph errors are, there's no guarantee I'd be able to answer it either way.

Comment: I understand. I am just loading a pdf from file in a simple SwiftUI view that uses this.... struct MyPDFView:View {
    
    let data:Data
    
    var body: some View {
        
        PDFKitRepresentedView(data, singlePage: false)
        
    }
}

Comment: Sounds like you likely don’t need the update method, then.

Comment: Right. I just don’t understand how the update call could work without that problem kicking in. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

There is some nice View Modifier available since iOS 14: **.quickLookPreview($url)**

```
@State var url: URL?
Button("PDF preview") {
  url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mypdfdocument", withExtension: "pdf")
}
 .quickLookPreview($url)
```