# How can I display a pdf in swiftui and enable actions such as saving and printing?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, pdfkit

I have used .fileImporter to import pdf files into my SwiftUI project.  I wish to be able to show a thumbnail of the pdf to the user and when he clicks on it, to open another page to view the pdf and be able to save or print it.

From what I have seen there is no native way to do this in swiftUI so I have used a representable for a PDFView but the layout is not quite right:

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let data: Data
    let size: CGSize

    init(_ data: Data, size: CGSize) {
        self.data = data
        self.size = size
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        // Create a `PDFView` and set its `PDFDocument`.
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: self.data)
        
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // this has no impact whatsoever on size
        uiView.frame.size = self.size
        uiView.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

Also, is there a standard way to access printing saving etc... or will these all be custom implementations?  Would it be easier to show the pdf in a browser to get that functionality?

The above code is from [How to implement PDF Viewer to SwiftUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658339/how-to-implement-pdf-viewer-to-swiftui-application)