# Is there a way to use PDFKit to only display selected part of a pdf?

Tags: swift, pdf, swiftui, swift5, pdfkit

I am trying to create a program that displays pdfs in chunks. So if you have a 100 page pdf and you only want to display the first chapter you could code something for only showing pages 1 - 10. I've searched around and as it stands it seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658339/how-to-implement-pdf-viewer-to-swiftui-application) is the best way to display pdfs. The problem is this loads the entire pdf at once in a reader. Going through the documentation now and I can't find anyway to selectively display the pdf. is there a way to selectively display pdf text using pdfkit? or will I have to use some other library for that?

I also see there's a [tabViewStyle(.page)](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-scrolling-pages-of-content-using-tabviewstyle) I can use to get a paged reader view in swiftui but I'd prefer not to have to format and prettify the text if possible.

I'm not opposed to using 3rd party libraries I just don't want to have to deal with formatting text or whatever. thanks!

Comment: sorry @KJ can you expand on your comment please? How can I split the pdf? that's where I'm really stuck right now. I was thinking of going through the document and iterating through each PDFPage but then i'm not sure how to make that into a PDFDocument

Comment: @KJ thanks for the explanation. that seems very complicated. would it be easier to implement this partial story view functionality using a .docx or .epub?

Comment: @KJ so do you have a suggestion on displaying chapters of a story using UIKit/SwiftUI? I'm considering a queue or something of PDFPages and somehow turning that into a document? or maybe just saving each page as an image with swiping in-between to mimic a book