# How to show a PDF from Data binary in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am receiving a base64 encoded file string from my backend which I know is a PDF. I have already decoded the base64 string into a Data object, I am just now confused as to how I can present this PDF data? I just need to present it in a simple View.

Comment: Take a look at [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit)

Comment: This may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65659435/560942